# How to use the Pending module in ActiveSupport

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, activesupport

I can't seem to make the Pending module in ActiveSupport::Testing work.

test/unit/pending.rb contains:

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'active_support/testing/pending'

class PendingTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include ActiveSupport::Testing::Pending

  pending "a pending case with a closure" do
     assert false
  end
end
```

But when I execute ruby unit/foo.rb, I get:

```
undefined method `pending' for PendingTest:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I looked in the code in pending.rb in the ActiveSupport gem.  The pending method is inside an
     unless defined?(Spec)
block, but I verified that Spec is not defined.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the `pending` method needs to be called inside a test, rather than on the class:

```
test "it works" do
  pending "well, it will eventually"
end
```

Comment: Cool, thanks.  I think I was mislead by the fact that the `pending` method takes a block as a parameter.  So you can still enclose the body of the test inside a pending block.  It seems like all asserts inside the block are *required* to fail, which I would not have expected...